# Does the spouse of a British citizen both living in Ireland with a Stamp 4 EUFam residence permit need a visa to travel to the UK?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

My Question is about whether the spouse of a British citizen, both living in Ireland, and the spouse being a South African citizen and passport holder with a Stamp 4 EUFam residence permit require a visa to travel to the UK?

Comment: Is the "stamp 4 EUFam" residence permit a separate card?  If so, does it say "residence permit of the family member of a union citizen," or words to that effect?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from an internet search that the "stamp 4 EUFam" card is Ireland's answer to Article 10 of the directive [2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  As such, it entitles the bearer to enter the UK without a visa when traveling with (or to join) the EU family member (in this case, the British citizen).  Details are available at [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).

Note that you may be asked to prove your relationship, so you should have your marriage certificate with you.  More details may be found on the linked gov.uk page, but these apply mostly to circumstances that seem unlikely given the situation presented in the question.

If the South African spouse wishes to travel to without the British spouse, then it will be necessary to have a UK visa.